# Powershell Filter doesn't accept comma

Tags: powershell, filter

I try to use the Get-User command with a simple Filter.

```
Get-User -Filter "(Manager -eq 'Max, Mustermann')"
```

The problem is that i get this exception:

> Cannot bind parameter 'Filter' to the target. Exception setting "Filter": "The value "Max, >Mustermann" could not be converted to type
> Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId.
> "(Manager -eq 'Max, Mustermann')" at position 34."
> In C:\Users\JAKO\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_4vtu0s13.ymv\tmp_4vtu0s13.ymv.psm1:38356 Zeichen:9
>
> - ```
>       $steppablePipeline.End()
>   ```
> - ```
>       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-User], ParameterBindingException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : >ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.GetUser

As far as I understand the Problem its because of the comma, so i tryed some workaorunds.

```
Get-User -Filter "(Manager -like 'Max, Mustermann')"
```

Here I dont get an exception but there are no Users that get returned.

```
Get-User -Filter "(Manager -eq 'Max"," Mustermann')"
```

The same as with the other workaround. No exception but no Users are Matching.
I also made sure that i have Users that would match this specift query, by using this command

```
Get-User -Filter | Format-List Manager
```

How can I write my Filter input so it matches "Max, Mustermann"?

Comment: Where does `Get-User` come from?

Comment: Is `Get-User` a proxy function?

Comment: The Get-User command comes from the exchange Powershell command list.

Comment: @XDDDEeKEK I'm asking about the function/command `Get-User` - which module did you install/import to get that command? If you don't know: `Get-Command Get-User |% Source`

Comment: its from the exchange PS

Comment: tmp_4vtu0s13.ymv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [filtering documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/filter-properties?view=exchange-ps) for the `Manager` attribute:

> This filter **requires the distinguished name or canonical distinguished name of the manager** (a mailbox or mail user). For example, `Get-User -Filter "Manager -eq 'CN=Angela Gruber,CN=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com'"` or `Get-Mailbox -Filter "Manager -eq 'contoso.com/Users/Angela Gruber'"`.
> To find the distinguished name of a manager, replace  with the name, alias, or email address of the recipient, and run this command: `Get-Recipient -Identity "<RecipientIdentity>" | Format-List Name,DistinguishedName`.

So now we know why the filter isn't working (a distinguished name is expected), and how to obtain the correct value (by using `Get-Recipient`):

```
# Fetch manager's user account object
$targetUser = Get-Recipient -Filter "SimpleDisplayName -eq 'Max, Mustermann'"

# Fetch reports 
Get-User -Filter "Manager -eq '$($targetUser.DistinguishedName)'"
```

Comment: Thank you very much.